# How to get pairwise distance for two lists of vectors in python

Tags: python, pairwise-distance

Say I got two lists of vectors:

```py
l1 = [v1, v2, v3]
l2 = [v4, v5, v6]
```

I know that with scipy I can get pairwise distances within a list but how do I do it for two so that the results look like that:

```py
[[d(v1, v4), d(v1, v5), d(v1,v6)],
 [d(v2, v4), d(v2, v5), d(v2, v6)],
 [d(v3, v4), d(v3, v4), d(v3, v4)]]
```

in the most efficient way possible? loops are best to be avoided.

Comment: Check [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes I know about cdist and pdist, Im asking how to use them for this particular arrangement

Comment: Well cdist works for two datasets, you can convert the list to numpy arrays and use cdist on them.

Comment: i will look into that, thanks

Comment: And...? Got it going for you?